# Interfacing Load Cell and HX711 with Raspberry Pi 3 using Python 3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, sensors

I am currently working on a IoT Project in which I am trying to **interface my Raspberry Pi 3 to HX711** so that I can read weight readings from my load cell having a range of 200 kg.

For the Python code, I tried [this Python library from github](https://github.com/j-dohnalek/hx711py)

According to the description of this repository, I first calibrated the HX711 (calibration.py) by using a 5 kg known weight, giving me the offset and scale. After which I copied them and used them in `example_python3.py`.

But I keep getting variable readings from the load cell as shown in the following screenshot from the Raspberry Pi window:

[image: Python Program Output]

I am getting this output by putting 5 kg load. I tried this loop of calibration and checking the output many many times but my output is still variable.

This is the code that I was using:

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import sys
from hx711 import HX711

# Force Python 3 ###########################################################

if sys.version_info[0] != 3:
    raise Exception("Python 3 is required.")

############################################################################
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

hx = HX711(5, 6)


def cleanAndExit():
    print("Cleaning...")
    GPIO.cleanup()
    print("Bye!")
    sys.exit()


def setup():
    """
    code run once
    """
    #Pasted Offset and Scale I got from calibration..
    hx.set_offset(8608276.3125)
    hx.set_scale(19.828315054835493)


def loop():
    """
    code run continuosly
    """
   
    try:

        val = hx.get_grams()
        print(val)
        hx.power_down()
        time.sleep(0.001)
        hx.power_up()


    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        cleanAndExit()


##################################

if __name__ == "__main__":

    setup()
    while True:
        loop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10669875). Could you [edit] your question and replace the image by the text instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not have an HX711 so I cannot test your code. But I can give some pointers that might help.

1. My main question is: why does your code contain

   ```py
   hx.power_down()
   time.sleep(0.001)
   hx.power_up()
   ```

   in the loop? According to the [datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ForceFlex/hx711_english.pdf), the output settling time (i.e. *the time from power up, reset, input channel change and gain change to valid stable output data*) is 400 ms. So if you power down the HX711 after every reading, every reading will be instable!
2. Furthermore, how much deviation between readings do you expect? Your values currently fluctuate between roughly 4990 and 5040, which is a difference of 50, so only 1% difference. That's not really bad. Unfortunately, the accuracy of the HX711 is not specified in the datasheet, so I can't determine if this is "correct" or "wrong". However, you should check what you can expect before assuming something is wrong. The data sheet mentions an input offset drift of 0.2 mV, while the full-scale differential input voltage (at gain 128) is 20 mV. That's 1% too. (That might be coincidence, but you should probably dive into it if you want to be sure.)
3. Did you check the timing of your serial communication? The code just toggles IO pins without any specific timing, while the datasheet mentions that PD_SCK must be high for at least 0.2 us and at most 50 us. Toggling faster might result in incorrect readings, while toggling slower might cause the device to reset (since keeping PD_SCK high for longer than 60 us causes it to enter power down mode). See for example [this C implementation](https://github.com/bogde/HX711/blob/master/src/HX711.cpp) which included a fix for fast CPUs. Your Python library did not include this fix.

   I'm not sure how you would enforce this using a Raspberry Pi, though. It seems like you're just lucky if you get this working reliably on a Raspberry Pi (or any other non-real-time platform), because if your code is interrupted in a bad time, the reading may fail (see [this comment](https://github.com/bogde/HX711/issues/203#issuecomment-860119798) for example).
4. I've read a few reports on the internet of persons stating that the HX711 needs to "warm up" for 2-3 minutes, so the readings become more stable after that time.
5. Finally, the issue could also be hardware related. There seem to be many low-quality boards. For example, there is [this known design fault](https://github.com/bogde/HX711/issues/172) that might be related.

**NB:** Also note that your offset (8,608,276.3125) can't be correct. The HX711 returns a 24-bit 2's complement value. That means a value between -8,388,607 and +8,388,608. Your value is outside that range. The reason that you got this value is that the library you're using is not taking the data coding into account correctly. See [this discussion](https://gist.github.com/underdoeg/98a38b54f889fce2b237). There are several forks of the repository in which this was fixed, for example [this one](https://github.com/tatobari/hx711py/). If correctly read, the value would have been -8,168,939.6875. This bug won't affect the accuracy, but could result in incorrect results for certain weights.

Just a final note for everyone thinking that the precision is 24-bit and thus it should return very reliable readings: **precision is not the same as accuracy**. Just because the device returns 24 bits does not mean that those bits are correct. How close the value is to the real value (the actual weight) depends on many other factors. Note that the library that you use by default reads the weight 16 times and averages the result. That shouldn't be necessary at all if the device is so accurate!

**My advice:**

- Remove the power down from your loop (you may want to use it once in your setup though).
- Wait at least 400 ms before your first reading.
- Fix the data conversion for 2's complement logic if you want to use the full range.
- Do not expect the device to be accurate to 24 bits.
- If you still want to improve the accuracy of the readings, you might want to dive into the hardware- or timing-related issues (the datasheet and [these github issues](https://github.com/bogde/HX711/issues) contain a lot of information).

Comment: Hii, Firstly Thanks for so Detailed Explanation. Do you know any other hardware which I can replace with HX711 (or more stable HX711 model or version) and also the code for that new Hardware(if any) that will be suitable for my question here.

Comment: @Rbogtx_0705, I'm not familiar with load cell amplifiers, and Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask for such recommendations. Your question was about a specifc problem and I tried to answer that as good as possible. Please upvote and/or accept if you think it helped you or answered the question. And I suggest to use Google or another electronics/arduino/hobby forum to search for alternatives if you decide to use another component.

Comment: Wow! What an answer! Helped us a lot, thanks!